# Configure BIND to forward unresolved requests to an upstream server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have an upstream DNS server which has an automated system to setup and maintain records to handle mail (e.g. `MX` and various others). However, I'd like to use a separate DNS server to handle the "real" DNS stuff...instead of updating the upstream DNS server.

Is there a way to setup the downstream DNS server to forward unfulfilled requests to the upstream DNS server? Both severs would be managing the same zones (with the downstream managing more), so I don't think I could use a `NS` as that would prevent the downstream from overriding/adding records.

Comment: what exactly are "unfulfilled" requests? are they in zones the servers are authoritative for, or are they other things?

Comment: E.g. if the upstream server has a MX record for example.com, but the downstream server doesn't (but may have other records for example.com). A MX request for example.com hitting the downstream server should be forwarded to the upstream server.

Comment: And if an A request for example.com hitting the downstream server should be fulfilled by the downstream server and __not__ be forwarded to the upstream server.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a feature for that in BIND. dnsmasq or other things might be able to do such transparent overlays, but I've never had a need to setup such a system.

Comment: Found this feature on knot: https://www.knot-dns.cz/docs/2.5/html/modules.html#fallback / https://www.knot-dns.cz/docs/2.5/html/modules.html#catch-nxdomain

Comment: You do not have to update the "upstream" DNS server. Just delegate a specific zone from the separate nameserver to the upstream one. Or use a CNAME to let recursive nameservers do their normal zone walking.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek read the second half of my question. I explain why that doesn't work.

Comment: Just create a new zone below the current one...

Comment: Can you please post an answer?